SEDE Data Query to find posts that have hidden comments added by me
Preface
I have developed a browser extension which is useful for stackexchange community users. It helps identify important or relevant information on any post based on their previous activity - It's called Stack Me First, do check it out if interested
One of the features it has is to identify if there are any comments/answers added by the user in the current post which are hidden by pagination.
Question
Now I want to create a Data Query to find any such post which could have hidden comments and return those questions so that I can add this query in my documentation to help the user in getting started with using the extension.
To be honest, I would like to get this done using Stack Exchange API, but I don't think it's possible.

I know we can use below query to fetch posts that I have commented on, but I want to improve this query by looking for posts with hidden comments
SELECT id, creationdate, text, postid AS [Post Link]
FROM Comments
WHERE UserId = '736172'


Or Is it possible to get the count of comments for each post in the above query?

To get the number of comments, you just need to add one line to the SELECT. As a result, the query will look like this:
SELECT 
  id, 
  creationdate, 
  text, 
  postid AS [Post Link],
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments AS c WHERE Comments.PostId = c.PostId) AS total_comments
FROM Comments
WHERE UserId = 736172
ORDER BY Id

Well, I found this post that describes the algorithm for displaying comments under a post. I wrote a query that does what is needed: finds all comments of a certain user if they are hidden by pagination and adds the total number of comments under the post. The final query looks like this:
WITH posts_with_user_comment AS (
  SELECT
    Posts.Id AS PostId
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    EXISTS (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        Comments
      WHERE
        UserId = ##UserId##
        AND Comments.PostId = Posts.Id
    )
),

all_comments_under_post AS (
  SELECT
    Comments.*
  FROM
    posts_with_user_comment
  JOIN
    Comments
  ON
    Comments.PostId = posts_with_user_comment.PostId
)

SELECT
  t.*,
  t.PostId AS [Post Link]
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    rank() over(PARTITION BY PostId ORDER BY Score DESC, CreationDate ASC) AS rnk,
    count(*) over(PARTITION BY PostId) AS total_post_comments
  FROM
    all_comments_under_post
) AS t
WHERE
  t.UserId = ##UserId##
  AND rnk > 5
ORDER BY
  PostId DESC
;


the query you mentioned in the edit returns all the comments, not just hidden comments. For example, when I run the query I get this post in the result which only has 1 comment.

This was done intentionally so that you can see that indeed comments with the is_hidden flag are actually hidden. I have now updated the query to display only those comments that are hidden by the pagination page.

Awesome, it works now. I actually did not notice the is_hidden column in the previous query.

Yes, of course.
